# Wav file "Invalid data found when processing input"

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

Thanks for paying attention.

I try to cut 3 seconds of 1000 wav-files. To do this, I chose FFMPEG through a `.bat`

Here is my code :

```
set i=0
for %%X in (sons_musique/*.wav) do (
echo Traitement de %%X... 
echo valeur de i %i%...
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.001 -i "sons_musique/%%X" -t 00:00:03.001 "sons_musique/extrait%i%.wav"
set /a i+=1)
```

Here is my issue :

```
Traitement de Musique (1).wav...
valeur de i 0...
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
sons_musique/Musique (1).wav: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Files are recognized into the loop.

Is it an isue from the I/O datas ?

What's wrong in these lines ? I tried to fix this issue by different ways and changing parameters. The syntax seems to be correct.

Thank you in advance for your attention and your help.

Comment: Need to see full log of command which reports this.

Comment: @Mulvya : Just edited with the full Log